# VBA login cant click button

Tags: excel, vba

Everything works up until I try to click the button.  The button does not have a name so i tried to get it by class. Any suggestions?

Button:

```
<input type="button" value="Sign On" class="ButtonSm" onclick="submitForm();">
```

My Code:

```
Dim IE

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = 1
IE.navigate "www.xxx.com"


Do While (IE.Busy)
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)

Loop

With IE.Document
        .getElementByID("USER").Value = UserName
        .getElementByID("PASSWORD").Value = Password
        .getElementByClassName("ButtonSm").Click
End With


End Sub
```

Comment: What is `submitForm()` doing?

Comment: function resetCredFields()
{
     document.Login.PASSWORD.value = "";
}

    function submitForm()
{
    document.Login.submit();
}

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CSS selectors:**

Try using a CSS selector to target the element.  The selector `input[value='Sign On'` targets the first element on the page found with `input` tag and having attribute `value` whose value is `'Sign On'`.

---

**Applying the selector with VBA:**

Applied via the `querySelector` method of `document`.

```
IE.document.querySelector("input[value='Sign On']").Click
```

You may also try

```
IE.document.querySelector("input[value='Sign On']").FireEvent "onclick"
```

---

**Other observations:**

There is not enough HTML nor an URL to advise further. You could potentially just submit the form directly with:

```
IE.document.forms(formIndexGoesHere).Submit
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error as before Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method.  Thanks anyways